# Parse a char string into an INT C programming

Tags: c, string, char, int

I'm trying to parse a char string into an INT.

If I had...

```
unsigned char color[] = "255"
```

And wanted to parse this into an INT.  How would I go about doing this?

I tried...

```
unsigned char *split;

split = strtok(color," ,.-");
while(split != NULL)
{
    split = strok(NULL, " ,.-);
}
```

This just gives me the value 255 for split now.

I feel like I need something like...

```
int y = split - '0';   //but this makes an INT pointer without a cast
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a string to integer, call `strtol`:

```
char color[] = "255";
long n;
char *end = NULL;
n = strtol(color, &end, 10);
if (*end == '\0') {
    // convert was successful
    // n is the result
}
```

Comment: @user3622460 glad to know it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert without calling strtol you can scan the `color` array and compare each `char` against `'0'` to get the corresponding numeric value, then add the result properly multiplied by a power of 10, i.e.

```
int i = 0, strlen = 0, result = 0;
while (color[i++]) strlen++;
for (i = 0; i<strlen; i++)
{
    result += (color[i] - '0')*pow(10,strlen-1-i);
}
```

Comment: I don't get the impression "without `strtol`" was OPs idea.